# About event-decline API, what caused the time difference?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-decline?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
I'm using this API in my application to decline an event as a room.
That works well, but sometimes the following problems occur.

The time of the API call and the time when the room does decline the event is different.
For example, my application called the API at 11:12:10 and got an "Accepted" response, but the room did NOT look "declined" in the Outlook Calendar. Later I got the event details through API call, the room's response time of the decline was a few hours later than expected (e.g., 13:10:00).

Is this kind of thing common?
It would be great if you could tell me how to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is the way currently it is implemented.
Being said that, consider filing [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so that it could be considered for future implementation.

Thanks.